# Ubuntu Server unable to create directory in PHP

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php

I have setup a little Ubuntu Server for developing some web apps.

I have a little script that uses mkdir() to create a directory, but i am getting a permission denied, its a simple command

```
mkdir($directory);
```

The error that im getting is

```
[Tue Jun 21 22:27:25.079075 2016] [:error] [pid 21150] [client 192.168.0.8:55413] PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in .........
```

Im also getting permission denied for a few other commands like ftp_get()

When i check the phpinfo() the upload_tmp_dir is set to no value.

I am not very good at server admin so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I setup the server from a tutorial, then setup my virtual host from another tutorial.

Thanks Guys :)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure Apache has permissions to write to directory where you are trying to create a new directory.

F.e. if your script is calling **mkdir('/var/www/subdir/newdir')**, run the following:

1. Give apache ownership: `sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/subdir`
2. Make directory writable: `sudo chmod 770 /var/www/subdir`